# Add code to current editor window in visual studio package/extention

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsix

How do you add/remove code in the code editor from an extension?

For example:
I created an extension witch modifies the code from an incoming socket
The example uses Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor

Tried using:

`IWpfTextView textView; // got from visual studio "Create" event
ITextChange change; // Got from network socket or other source`

ITextEdit edit = textView.TextBuffer.CreateEdit(); // Throws "Not Owner" Exception 
edit.Delete(change.OldSpan);
edit.Insert(change.NewPosition, change.NewText);

But I guess there's another way because the CrateEdit() Function fails

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Error: Attempted to edit TextBuffer on the wrong thread.  
And "textView.TextBuffer.TakeThreadOwnership();" throws:  
Attempted to change edit thread of TextBuffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are attempting to do an edit on an `ITextBuffer` from a different thread than the one that owns it.  This is simply not possible.  `ITextBuffer` instances are affinitized to a particular thread once the first edit occurs and after that point they cannot be edited from a different thread.  The `TakeThreadOwnership` method will also fail after the `ITextBuffer` has been affinitized.  Most other non-editing methods (`CurrentSnapshot` for example) can be called from any thread.

Typically an `ITextBuffer` will be affinitized to the Visual Studio UI thread.  So to perform the edit use the original `SynchronizationContext.Current` instance or `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` from the UI thread to get back onto the UI thread and then perform the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I figure out

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {

            ITextEdit edit = _view.TextBuffer.CreateEdit();
            ITextSnapshot snapshot = edit.Snapshot;

            int position = snapshot.GetText().IndexOf("text:");
            edit.Delete(position, 5);
            edit.Insert(position, "some text");
            edit.Apply();
        }));
```